# Really annoying character encoding issue with a PHP form

Tags: php, html

I'm having a really annoying issue with special characters in a PHP HTML form, everything is UTF-8 yet the special characters still show up as question marks...

Here is my current PHP code and i was hoping one of you would notice the issue...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "utf-8");
if(isset($_POST['fyrirtaeki'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "hafsteinn@tikktakk.is";
$email_subject = "SKILAGREIN";


function died($error) {
    // your error code can go here
    echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['fyrirtaeki']) ||
    !isset($_POST['kennitala']) ||
    !isset($_POST['heimilisfang']) ||

    !isset($_POST['laun-1']) ||
    !isset($_POST['kenn-1']) ||
    !isset($_POST['timabil-1']) ||
    !isset($_POST['afdregid-1']) ||


    !isset($_POST['sum']) ||
    !isset($_POST['dags']) ||


    !isset($_POST['simi'])) {
    died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
}
$fyrirtaeki = $_POST['fyrirtaeki'];
$kennitala = $_POST['kennitala'];
$netfang = "medlag@medlag.is";
$heimilisfang = $_POST['heimilisfang'];
$simi = $_POST['simi'];

$dags = $_POST['dags'];
$sum = $_POST['sum'];

$laun1 = $_POST['laun-1'];
$kenn1 = $_POST['kenn-1'];
$timabil1 = $_POST['timabil-1'];
$afdregid1 = $_POST['afdregid-1'];


$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

$email_message = "Upplýsingar má finna hér að neðan.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "Fyrirtæki: ".clean_string($fyrirtaeki)."\n";
$email_message .= "Kennitala: ".clean_string($kennitala)."\n";
$email_message .= "Heimilisfang: ".clean_string($heimilisfang)."\n";
$email_message .= "Sími: ".clean_string($simi)."\n\n\n";


if ($laun1 != "") {
$email_message .= "Nafn launþega: ".clean_string($laun1)."\n";
$email_message .= "Kennitala: ".clean_string($kenn1)."\n";
$email_message .= "Launatímabil: ".clean_string($timabil1)."\n";
$email_message .= "Afdregid: ".clean_string($afdregid1)."\n\n";
}


$email_message .= "Skilagrein greidd dags:".clean_string($dags)."\n";
$email_message .= "Samtals: ".clean_string($sum)."\n\n\n\n";




// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$netfang."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$netfang."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!-- include your own success html here -->

Takk fyrir, eyðublað móttekið.

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Try using a different font as the one that you are using might not support UTF-8 characters.

Comment: Did you save your file with UTF8-without-bom encoding ?

Comment: What do the email headers look like, when you view a message sent this way, in an email client using “raw mode” or “message source” or whatever it is called?

Comment: This script only returns a bit of text (error or success handling). Where does it return to? Is the script accessed by an XHR request or a regular POST? In case of XHR you need to make sure the charset of the form page is also UTF-8.

Comment: Just to be clear, is the problem in the email that is being sent, or in the HTML page that is output by the program? (hint: if it's the email, I can't see anything setting the charset in the mail headers)

Comment: have you tried `mb_send_mail`? http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-send-mail.php